# Virtual host conf file redirect adds local file path

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm adding the following rewrite to the conf file for my virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
.... A bunch of aliases here
```

The site works fine with the www. but if you enter the domain without the www. the site will be redirected to www.example.com/home/example/public_html - it adds the file path. How can I prevent this?

Here's the aliases:

```
Alias /index.php /home/cms/public/index.php
Alias /skins/admin /home/cms/public/skins/admin
AliasMatch ^/scripts/(\w+)/admin/(\w+)\.js /home/cms/modules/$1/scripts/admin/$2.js
AliasMatch ^/scripts/(\w+)/(\w+)\.js /home/cms/modules/$1/scripts/$2.js
Alias /scripts /home/cms/public/scripts 
AliasMatch (?i)^/flash/([A-Za-z]*)/([A-Za-z_]*).swf$ /home/cms/public/flash/$1/$2.swf
Alias /css /home/cms/public/css
Alias /thirdparty /home/cms/public/thirdparty
RewriteEngine off
<Directory /home/cms>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
</Location>
```

Comment: Can you provide some information about your aliases? The request should be working like this.

Comment: Can there be rules at a higher level that your vhosts config? public_html are usually use for per user configurations.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), you should have the local path in the regex, before the grouping:

```
RewriteRule ^\/home\/example(.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Also according to the docs:

> On the first RewriteRule [the Pattern] is applied
>   to the (%-decoded) URL-path of the
>   request; subsequent patterns are
>   applied to the output of the last
>   matched RewriteRule.

This would suggest you have other RewriteRules prior to that one.